# Reading data from a custom log in azure log analytics

Tags: azure, kql

I have linked the following log itno azure log anlytic environment via customer log

```
2023-01-24 07:58:30[X:MoveCarddataShare_Start]
2023-01-24 07:58:30[X;MoveCarddataShare_FileTomove:SA\Dispatch\)
2023-01-24 07:58:30[X;MoveCarddataShare_FileCountTomove:2)
2023-01-24 07:58:32[X;MoveCarddataShare_FileTomove:Styled and Co\Dispatch\)
2023-01-24 07:58:32[X;MoveCarddataShare_FileCountTomove:2)
```

I want to now the value of X (which is the client) and then the action and then the result

THe following code works

```
let temp =
    ShelSA_cardMovment_CL
    | parse RawData with * "[" C
    | parse RawData with * ";" A
    | parse RawData with * "^" R
    | extend dt = substring(RawData,0,19)
                ,Client = split(C,";",0)
                ,Action = split(A,"^",0)
                ,Re = R;
temp
|extend Result= replace_string(tostring(Re),')','')
```

But all resulting columns have "[ ]" around the output  the replace will remove it but it seems ungainly

```
["ShellSA"]
["MoveCarddataShare_FileTomove"]
Symon\Dispatch\)
```

Also, I wondered if this is the best way

This is the CV output I want

| Datetime of action | Client | Action | Re | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24/01/2023 07:58 | "[""X:MoveCarddataShare^Start\r\n""]" | "[""""]" | "Start" | "Start" |
| 24/01/2023 07:58 | "[""X""]" | "[""MoveCarddataShare_FileTomove""]" | "SA\Dispatch)" | "SA\Dispatch" |
| 24/01/2023 07:58 | "[""X""]" | "[""MoveCarddataShare_FileCountTomove""]" | "2)" | "2" |
| 24/01/2023 07:58 | "[""X""]" | "[""MoveCarddataShare_FileTomove""]" | "Styled and Co\Dispatch)" | "Styled and Co\Dispatch" |
| 24/01/2023 07:58 | "[""X""]" | "[""MoveCarddataShare_FileCountTomove""]" | "2)" | "2" |
| 24/01/2023 07:58 | "[""X""]" | "[""MoveCarddataShare_FileTomove""]" | "Symon\Dispatch)" | "Symon\Dispatch" |
| 24/01/2023 07:58 | "[""X""]" | "[""MoveCarddataShare_FileCountTomove""]" | "3)" | "3" |
| 2023-01-23 14:51:25 | "[""X:MoveCarddataShare_DateofFilemove\r\n""]" | "[""""]" |  |  |
| 24/01/2023 07:58 | "[""X""]" | "[""MoveCarddataShare_LastfileMoved""]" | "New Text Document.txt)" | "New Text Document.txt" |
| 24/01/2023 07:58 | "[""X""]" | "[""MoveCarddataShare_Movefiledcount""]" | "14)" | "14" |
| 24/01/2023 07:58 | "[""X""]" | "[""MoveCarddataShare""]" | "End" | "End" |

Comment: The code and the result it produces does not seem to make much sense. Please provide the required result in a CSV format.

Comment: Still doesn't make much sense, and also doesn't match your sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you are looking for

```
datatable(RawData:string)
[
    @"2023-01-24 07:58:30[X:MoveCarddataShare_Start]"
   ,@"2023-01-24 07:58:30[X;MoveCarddataShare_FileTomove:SA\Dispatch\)"
   ,@"2023-01-24 07:58:30[X;MoveCarddataShare_FileCountTomove:2)"
   ,@"2023-01-24 07:58:32[X;MoveCarddataShare_FileTomove:Styled and Co\Dispatch\)"
   ,@"2023-01-24 07:58:32[X;MoveCarddataShare_FileCountTomove:2)"
]
| parse kind=regex flags=U RawData with Timestamp:datetime @"\[" Client "[;:]" Action @"[]:]" Result @"\)?$"
```

| RawData | Timestamp | Client | Action | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-24 07:58:30[X:MoveCarddataShare_Start] | 2023-01-24T07:58:30Z | X | MoveCarddataShare_Start |  |
| 2023-01-24 07:58:30[X;MoveCarddataShare_FileTomove:SA\Dispatch) | 2023-01-24T07:58:30Z | X | MoveCarddataShare_FileTomove | SA\Dispatch\ |
| 2023-01-24 07:58:30[X;MoveCarddataShare_FileCountTomove:2) | 2023-01-24T07:58:30Z | X | MoveCarddataShare_FileCountTomove | 2 |
| 2023-01-24 07:58:32[X;MoveCarddataShare_FileTomove:Styled and Co\Dispatch) | 2023-01-24T07:58:32Z | X | MoveCarddataShare_FileTomove | Styled and Co\Dispatch\ |
| 2023-01-24 07:58:32[X;MoveCarddataShare_FileCountTomove:2) | 2023-01-24T07:58:32Z | X | MoveCarddataShare_FileCountTomove | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA52RTUvDQBCG74H8h2HxYKCFuFUsW4qWFG9emgrCJsjaHZPFzSbsTq2CP96t9Faq4sxlvt6HF0Yrivls8XyldstYikDeuCZLE5kmEOOW8ZxPxvnFmF9Cfi2upmKSy0dx379hobzWUVS2yuNTScpTzb5loxOy2bHszlhc912ci3JRLU0YFG3aKvsXqOi3jg40/hOC/%20qFPixqUE5D0f/N1mnmka06TT5hUD4gvBqn5x4bfIcXq5owf4DDL2BnqIW16TCQ6gYRmUixiz%20pJIPCGnQETM5EzWCxIdO7uJL1vl1h2FraX2Y3Z%20wLqLNMvucBAAA=)